# How can I disable the HTTP TRACE method in Laravel Forge?

Tags: laravel, http-trace

I have an application that needs to pass a security review. I'm using Laravel Forge and the item in question is:

> The application web server must be configured to disable the TRACE and
>   other HTTP methods if not being used.

I tested it using

```
curl -v -X TRACE http://www.yourserver.com
```

via this guide:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31659/testing-for-http-trace-method

And it didn't return an error message so I'm assuming that I still need to disable TRACE.

What's the best way to accomplish this using Laravel Forge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your nginx configuration in Forge, so you just need to add a method filter in your conf:

```
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) 
{
    return 444;
}
```